# What "designs" is Dr Yueh referring to?

Tags: dune, dune-2021

In *Dune* (2021), Dr. Yueh checks vitals on Paul before Paul meets Bene Gesserit:

> Dr. Yueh: The Bene Gesserit say they serve the greater good...
> But, meaning no disrespect to your lady mother...
> they also serve their own **designs**.

What "designs" is Dr Yueh referring to?

Comment: Well, we know that they have very long-scale (secret) plans to create a superhuman. Yueh just means that they have their own agenda, whatever that may be, and aren't as benign as they seem at first glance

Comment: Not only that, Yueh might not know exactly what their designs are.

Comment: Some kind of midi dress with a french collar maybe?

Comment: @DannyMcG, who puts a french collar on a midi dress? and on a *desert* planet? That sand gets *everywhere*.

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/design - see entry 2 " a particular purpose or intention held in view by an individual or group"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To the outside observer, the Bene Gesserit can appear to be a mysterious cult which has insinuated itself into positions of influence. They are called "witches", because they exhibit abilities and powers that outsiders do not understand and are fearful of.

Who knows what plans (designs) such a group may have?

Interestingly, Yueh was himself married to a Bene Gesserit. However, it is unlikely that she was completely open with him.

Even Jessica holds some secrets from Leto (such as having Paul suffer through the Gom Jabbar), despite loving him enough to disobey her orders to only produce female offspring that could be married off to selected genetically compatible suitors in order to achieve their goal of a Kwisatz Haderach.